Failed to parse the JSON document caused by The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty
I am beginner in Rest Assured, while trying to access the response in a string format, i have encountered issue as such

The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty

and my base code is
PrintStream log = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Log.txt"));
RequestSpecification req = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com")
        .setContentType("application/json")
        .build();

// Define the ResponseSpecification to expect a status code of 201
ResponseSpecification res = new ResponseSpecBuilder()
        .expectStatusCode(201)
        .build();

// Method to make API request
public void addAPI() {
    // Create the request object for the Google Maps API
    Googlemapssetters map = new Googlemapssetters();
    Location location = new Location();
    location.setLatitude(23.763);
    location.setLongi(31.895);
    map.setLocation(location);
    map.setAccuracy(57);
    map.setLangauge("Tamil");
    map.setAddress("119, Misa Washington street, kk nagar");
    map.setName("Abimanyau");
    map.setPhone("6872658285");
    List<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
    types.add("Fridge");
    types.add("Geyser");
    map.setTypes(types);
    map.setWebsite("www.jaslogo.com");

    // Sending the API request
    Response resp = given()
            .spec(req)
            .queryParam("key", "qaclick123")
            .header("Content-type", "application/json")
            .body(map)
            .log().all()
        .when()
            .post("/maps/api/place/add/json")
        .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract()
            .response();
    System.out.println(resp.jsonPath().prettyPrint());

    // Handling response
    if (resp.getStatusCode() == 200 || resp.getStatusCode() == 201) {
        System.out.println(resp.asString()); --> Got the error here
}

I tried resp.asString() in restassured but got "Failed to parse the JSON document" caused by The "JSON input text should neither be null nor empty" to get response body
I am expecting the response code to be printed out in the console


The JSON input text should neither be null nor empty

This error is generated because the response body is empty. I just simulated the request you are using and I only see response headers (not a JSON response body), check the input parameters, such that a JSON response is received.

